# What do villages in the Warhammer Fantasy world look like?

Tags: wfrp-2e, warhammer, wfrp

While there's plenty information on cities and even some towns or single homesteads in official sources, I haven't been able to find much info about villages.

Medieval ones are rather spacious settlements surrounded by farming fields, orchards, pastures and whatever else. However, given the dangers of the Old World, I'd imagine villages here to be really dense and cramped, surrounded by a palisade to protect its inhabitants from beastmen, mutants and everything else that roams local wilderness.

So, is there some official answer in WFRP sources about how villages look?

Comment: "*is there some official answer in WFRP sources about how villages look?*" Out of curiosity, how far have you looked? Core only? Core and some region supplements? And what realm are you looking for info? Realms are vastly different from one another.

Comment: First I've checked in Sigmar's Heirs, since I know there's no info on villages in core. I've checked whichever supplements came into my mind, mostly Imperial ones, but there was no info to be found. Surprisingly enough, there was an example village in Game Master's Pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While most obvious place to look for information on Imperial villages would be in Sigmar's Heirs, definitive guide to the Empire, there's none. However, there is an example Reikland village in Game Master's Pack.

Villages usually have some fortifications:

> Since most of the Empire is covered by vast areas of untamed forest
>   inhabited by all manner of wild and unfriendly creatures (huge bears,
>   Goblins, and Beastmen), villages are usually protected by some sort of
>   defensive wall and/or ditch. The village of Kleindorf is fortunate
>   enough to have both. The protection is made from a combination of
>   drystone walls, log palisades, and picket fences—hardly enough to
>   deter an organised assault, but sufficient to delay bandit raids and
>   keep out marauding wild animals.

There's approximately 35 acres of land protected by fortifications, which is a lot for 74 villagers in Kleindorf. Of course, cultivated land is outside the palisade. Most of 25 buildings are located around a village centre, but some are further apart from it.

Since this is a "typical Reikland village", one can safely assume that villages usually aren't dense and crowded at all.

Comment: Worth noting is that Reikland is one of the richer provinces, so the other provinces might have villages with poorer defenses and less guards.

Comment: Less than two in Kleinsdorf? `To defend Kleindorf, each family takes a turn
providing a watchman for the two gates to the village, sited across
the only real road.` That's not much.

Answer (score -1):

The nature of societies differs across the old world. Your conception of the setting fits more or less with the Empire, which is modelled on rennaisance era Germany. Large towns and cities have some industry and skilled workers. They also each have a standing militia of well-drilled citizens and may have fortifications. (Empire army book, 6th edition)

Bretonnia has a much more rural, feudal structure. The vast majority of the population are serfs with no combat capability, lorded over by a powerful knightly class. (Bretonnia army book, 5th edition)

Tilea is a peninsula divided into many coastal city-states, where trade abounds and a general can find a profusion of mercenary companies to hire. 
http://warhammerfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Tilea

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can take the [tour] for a quick site introduction. This answer could probably be improved by referencing or quoting from the sources where you obtained this information. Thank you for participating!

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't see the last sentence asking for WFRP sources. My knowledge is limited to the tabletop game. Should I delete my answer?